# 3 dimension circle(scatter) plot with bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, bokeh

Hello StackOverflow good friends.

I have PCA results dataframe and I want to make 3d circle plot using bokeh.

I can make 2d circle plot easily.

like below code..

```
  Bp_source = ColumnDataSource(data=df_PCA)

  Bp_tools = ['pan','box_select', 'wheel_zoom', 'hover', 'reset','save','help']

  Bp_TOOLTIPS = [
      ("SampleID", "@id"),
      ("(PCA1, PCA2)","(@PCA1, @PCA2)")    
              ]

  Bp_plot = figure(
      tools=Bp_tools, tooltips=Bp_TOOLTIPS,
      plot_width=500, plot_height=500,
      x_axis_label='PCA1', y_axis_label='PCA2'
  )
  Bp_plot.circle('PCA1', 'PCA2',
                 source=Bp_source,
                 size=9,
                 color='color',
                 alpha=0.3,
                 legend='legend'
                )

  show(Bp_plot)
```

attatched figures are dataframe form and 2d plot.
[image]

So, I want to make 3d plot using PCA1,2 and 3.

Please share your fantastic code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh does not have any 3d plotting capability built-in. That is out-of-scope for the core library. The only way to have a 3d plot would be to write a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) yourself, e.g. similar to [this example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/wrapping.html#userguide-extensions-examples-wrapping)

Comment: oh... I couldn't find any example because of that kinds reason..
THANKS!!